# Find rows dublicated by (adding two coumns) rows

Tags: oracle

This code is not filtering **double rows** by (**serym+number**) -> table1. I couldn't manage to filter the table. Could you help to solve this problem:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t, table2 m
 WHERE
 t.serym= m.serym
 AND t.number= m.number
 AND m.serym in ('AA', 'AB', 'AC')
 AND m.tin is null 
 GROUP BY t.ns10_code,
          t.ns11_code,
          t.tin,
          t.serym 
 HAVING count(t.serym || t.number) > 1;
```

Thanks to all your answers.

[image]

Comment: Outcome must be Yellow rows

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
select t.ns10_code,
          t.ns11_code,
          t.tin,
          t.serym -- only columns can be used which are used in the GROUP BY
  from table1 t join table2 m on t.serym= m.serym
                and t.number = m.number
 where m.serym in ('AA', 'AB', 'AC')
 and m.tin is null 
 group by t.ns10_code,
          t.ns11_code,
          t.tin,
          t.serym 
 having count(t.serym || '-' || t.number) > 1; -- changed the expression
```

**-- update**

```
select * from
(select t.*,
        count(1) over (partition by t.serym, t.number) as cnt
  from table1 t join table2 m on t.serym= m.serym
                and t.number = m.number
 where m.serym in ('AA', 'AB', 'AC')
 and m.tin is null)
 where cnt > 1;
```

Also, If it is not what you are looking for, then share what is the error you are getting or what is wrong with the outcome.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. Other ways to solve?

Comment: The outcome is the rows that are not dublicate

Comment: Not duplicate or duplicate? please share the expected outcome altogether different image or other way. our group by contains the columns which is not unique for highlighted records

Comment: If it worked for you then Please accept the answer so that your question is marked as resolved.